# How to install PySide on CentOS?

Tags: python, installation, centos, pyside, yum

I want to install ReText on CentOS. Have a problem,

```
[root@localhost scripts-2.6]# python retext.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retext.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ReText import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebKit, datadirs, globalSettings
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ReText/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
ImportError: No module named PySide
```

Then I typed `yum install PySide` and `yum install python-pyside` to install PySide, and got the message **No package available.**

Also I tried `yum search pyside` and `yum search python-`, but that did not find the PySide package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CentOS repository does not contain PySide.
You can add the EPEL repository to your OS then use: **yum install -y python-pyside**
and it will be installed on your system.

In order to install the EPEL repository for 64bit systems, run the following as root:

1. cd /tmp
2. wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
3. rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

If you're using a 32bit system, use the following in step 2:

wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

Comment: **It works!**   


 Thanks a lot.  


**P.S.** 

   
My system is 32-bit.

Comment: Why could not add a linebreak by this     `End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak:`

Comment: Remus, have you added the EPEL repository for your appropriate system architecture? This package is not available on the stock CentOS repos.

Comment: PySide is not (currently) available for CentOS 7.  If you are not on CentOS 6 your best option is to build from Source.  Its very simple using the BuildScripts for fedora - see http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_PySide_on_Linux the easy way

Comment: Completed 1, 2, 3. Ran `yum ...`: `Error: Unable to find a match: python-pyside`

Answer (score 4):

There is no "python-pyside" package in EPEL 7:
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/letter_p.group.html

That is why you can't use the proposed by Nir Ben-Or solution for CentOS 7.

I have solved this with pip install, however you may need to install some prerequisites first.

1) install RPM packages (UPDATED thanks to @fredrik for a comment):

```
qt-webkit-devel
libxml2-devel
libxslt-devel
rpmdevtools
gcc
gcc-c++
qt-devel
cmake
python-devel
python-pip
```

Build of `pyside` should tell you if some RPM-s are missing.

2) if you qmake program is not "/usr/bin/qmake" you may need to do something like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 /usr/bin/qmake
```

3) install pyside via pip (this will take some time for build to complete):

```
sudo pip install pyside
```

Comment: For CentOS 7 you are missing some RPM packages in step 1: `qt-webkit-devel`, `libxml2-devel`, `libxslt-devel`, `rpmdevtools`, `gcc`, `gcc-c++`

Answer (score 2):

This is for CentOS 7.

First, make sure you've got the prerequisites:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install cmake qt-devel qt-webkit-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python-devel rpmdevtools gcc gcc-c++ make python-pip
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 /usr/bin/qmake
```

Now you should be able to install PySide:

```
sudo pip install PySide
```

Comment: I get `Error: Unable to find a match: qt-devel qt-webkit-devel python-devel python-pip`