# How to import libpyside.so as module

Tags: python, pip, ctypes, pyside2

After a `yum` install of `python-pyside` on `Centos 6`, how do I import the `libpyside.so` library in Python as a module?

https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Binaries_Linux

I played with the Python ctypes module for importing the `.so` file, but I'm not sure how to convert it into a module. On `Centos 7`, I can `pip install PySide2` and things work fine.

Pip doesn't seem to have a Centos 6 distribution for PySide2, so I thought the library installation method would circumvent things...

```
Python 3.4.8 (default, Apr  9 2018, 11:43:18)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> PySide2 = CDLL("libpyside.so")
>>> from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PySide2'
>>> PySide2
<CDLL 'libpyside.so', handle 10ffb10 at 7fb7c64f5400\>
```

If I have this all wrong, please tell me what libpyside.so is supposed to used for?

Comment: Did you run `pip3 install PySide2`? I didn't use it but I doubt *ctypes* is the way to go. It should be via *import*.

Comment: It returns "No matching distribution found for PySide2"

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935571/how-to-install-pyside-on-centos?

Comment: Yeah, I could try to downgrade from PySide2 to PySide and see if my program still works. I missed that binaries on https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Binaries_Linux are not for PySide2 but older PySide Qt4 I think. In which case, I'll probably just stick with PySide2.